# Phonegap web sql database creation error: no such table: cacheGroups

Tags: sqlite, cordova, web-sql

I'm developing a mobile application using Phonegap. My app has a web sql database in it. The first time the app is launched the database is created and populated. Below the code that I am using for the database creation:

```
    var db = window.openDatabase('littera', '1.0', 'Littera DB', 5 * 1024 * 1024);

        db.transaction(function(tx) {
          tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS quote (id integer primary key, author_id integer, category text, content text, favourite integer)');
          tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS author (id integer primary key, name text, short_bio text, media text)');
          callback();
        }, function(e) {
            console.log("ERROR CREATING DB: " + e.message);
            callback();
        });
```

The first time I launch the app the following error relative to the database creation happens (notice that this happens only the first time, the app works perfectly on all other launches):

```
01-01 23:57:41.600: E/SQLiteLog(1944): (1) no such table: CacheGroups
01-01 23:57:41.600: D/WebKit(1944): ERROR: 
01-01 23:57:41.600: D/WebKit(1944): Application Cache Storage: failed to execute statement "DELETE FROM CacheGroups" error "no such table: CacheGroups"
01-01 23:57:41.600: D/WebKit(1944): external/webkit/Source/WebCore/loader/appcache/ApplicationCacheStorage.cpp(558) : bool WebCore::ApplicationCacheStorage::executeSQLCommand(const WTF::String&)
01-01 23:57:41.600: E/SQLiteLog(1944): (1) no such table: Caches
01-01 23:57:41.600: D/WebKit(1944): ERROR: 
01-01 23:57:41.600: D/WebKit(1944): Application Cache Storage: failed to execute statement "DELETE FROM Caches" error "no such table: Caches"
01-01 23:57:41.600: D/WebKit(1944): external/webkit/Source/WebCore/loader/appcache/ApplicationCacheStorage.cpp(558) : bool WebCore::ApplicationCacheStorage::executeSQLCommand(const WTF::String&)
01-01 23:57:41.600: E/SQLiteLog(1944): (1) no such table: Origins
01-01 23:57:41.600: D/WebKit(1944): ERROR: 
01-01 23:57:41.600: D/WebKit(1944): Application Cache Storage: failed to execute statement "DELETE FROM Origins" error "no such table: Origins"
01-01 23:57:41.600: D/WebKit(1944): external/webkit/Source/WebCore/loader/appcache/ApplicationCacheStorage.cpp(558) : bool WebCore::ApplicationCacheStorage::executeSQLCommand(const WTF::String&)
01-01 23:57:41.600: E/SQLiteLog(1944): (1) no such table: DeletedCacheResources
```

The tables that generate the errors are not my own tables, but some tables created by web sql behind the scenes to do his own magic. I suppose something goes wrong during the database creation, since I do not have the same mistakes on later launches. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided complete details.

From your question it seems that you are using a **third** party library that auto-creates the DB in the sqlite on **startup**.
It can be inferred from the table names **CacheGroups, Caches, and DeletedCacheResources** that the APP uses these tables to store **CACHED** information to increase performance.
Since these are tables for storing data once the APP is running, they will **not** be avaiable during the **first** run of the APP. That's the reason I think during the **first run** of the APP it gives the error.
Once you have started using the APP, it creates the **cached tables** and starts using them during the next subsequent runs.

In order to avoid the error in the APP, you need to write logic to prevent the **cached table** logic from running at the first run.
You need to create/store some variable that will persist when the first time the APP is run and then use the variable to prevent the cached table logic being run.
e.g Pseudo code.

```
Get the App_first_run variable.

if ( App_first_run == true )
{
   Do not run the cached table logic.
}
```

Comment: I'm not using any third part library for the database, webkit browsers have built in support for web sql (and a phonegap app runs inside the webkit-based system browser). Those tables are created by the browser whenever I create a new database.

Comment: I have not seen such errors at least for the Apps that I had developed. Is the error causing any issues to your APP. If not I would suggest that you ignore it, as it may pertain to the internal working of cordova. which version of cordova are you developing on?

Comment: I'm using Phonegap 4.1.2-0.22.10. Yes, on the first startup of the app it fails to fetch some data from the DB.